# Point Alpha in Julia Scatter Plot

Tags: julia

I have a scatter plot:

```
using Plots
scatter(rand(1000), rand(1000))
```

[image]

How can I reduce the alpha of the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the keyword `alpha`

```
scatter(rand(1000), rand(1000), alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]